# GET API request to produce new data

Tags: api, rest, post, get, put

Given a raw data set and some operations, is it valid to apply those operations on the raw data and return the results to a client in a `GET` request? Raw data and operations are stored/created using a `POST` request and they are updated using a `PUT` request. In this `GET` request stored resources (raw data in operations) are not modified but it creates some new data using the stored data and sends it to the client.

Comment: REST is about representing a resource. An image is just raw data with rules applied, e.g. /api/image/123/square could represent the raw data of an image in square format. If the new data isn't stored then it's not a new resource

Comment: If I want to create a REST API to provide image processing capability(assuming we already have endpoints to CRUD source images) how can I create an endpoint that applies a designated filter to a source image? Do I go and create something like GET /api/factory/filter?img_id=&filter_id=? Since this endpoint doesn't modify any stored resource (as it applies the filter to the source image and sends the output as a response to the user) can we still call this a REST API?

Comment: you're filtering the resource (image) so you could use /api/image/{image_id}/filter/{filter_id}. /api/factory/filter is more like rpc than rest

Answer (score 0):

A **GET** request should be idempotent and should not modify any stored resource in database. Your requirement satisfies the above, since you are just returning the results.